Can this constraint be linearized?
I have a clustering problem with items that have non negative weights $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$.
$x_{ij}$ is a binary variable that takes value $1$ if item $i$ is assigned to cluster $j$, and $\gamma_j$ is a non negative continuous variable for cluster $j$ defined below.
I have the following constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j}x_{ij} &= 1 \quad &\text{for each item } i \tag{1}\\
\gamma_j &=  \frac{\sum_{i}\alpha_i \cdot \beta_i \cdot x_{ij}}{\sum_{i}\alpha_i\cdot x_{ij}} \quad &\text{for each cluster } j \tag{2}
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ makes sure each item is assigned to exactly one cluster, and constraint $(2)$ defines a weighted sum of cluster $j$, more specifically the sum of the $\beta_i$ coefficients of items assigned to cluster $j$, weighted by coefficients $\alpha_i.$
Is it possible to linearize constraint $(2)$ ?

You might be interested in Hexaly to solve your clustering problem, especially if it is large-scale: https://www.hexaly.com/benchmark/hexaly-vs-gurobi-k-means-clustering-mssc. No need to linearize expression (2); you can write it as is. Hexaly is free for academics; if it is for business, you can try it for free for 1 month.

@Hexaly I will take a look, thanks. When you say "no need to linearize the expression", does this mean that it is done automatically under the hood? Or that it is solved as a non linear problem?

Your Hexaly model is not automatically binarized and linearized; it is solved using nonlinear and combinatorial algorithmic techniques.

First multiply both sides by the denominator to obtain
$$\sum_i\alpha_i \gamma_j x_{ij} = \sum_i\alpha_i \beta_i  x_{ij}$$
Then linearize the resulting products $\gamma_j x_{ij}$ as described in How to linearize the product of a binary and a non-negative continuous variable?

If you only need to bound $\gamma_j$ from below, please note that $x_{ij} = x_{ij}^2$ facilitate the reformulation
\begin{align}
\gamma_j &\geq \frac{\sum_{i}\alpha_i \cdot \beta_i \cdot x_{ij}}{\sum_{i}\alpha_i\cdot x_{ij}} = \frac{\sum_{i} \left(\sqrt{\alpha_i \cdot \beta_i} \cdot x_{ij}\right)^2}{\sum_{i}\alpha_i\cdot x_{ij}}
\end{align}
which can be represented by a single second-order cone. Although nonlinear constraints sounds scary, I can ensure you that mixed-integer second-order cone optimization is quite mature and fast. The benefit, of course, is a strong relaxation leading to smaller search trees.
In the notation of the MOSEK Cookbook, this would be a rotated quadratic cone
\begin{align}
2 u \gamma_j \geq \sum_{i} (v_{ij})^2 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad (u,\gamma_j,v_{:j}) \in Q_r,
\end{align}
where $u = \frac 12\sum_{i}\alpha_i x_{ij}$ and $v_{ij} = \sqrt{\alpha_i \beta_i} x_{ij}$.
